# Where am I hiding?

Tags: word

Can a dangerous criminal be caught?
I ran away from the police.
Peruse this list of crimes.
Chin and neck doctors were robbed.
Spa in the Netherlands is no longer one of my hiding spots.

Comment: Bra, zilch ideas about where you might be.
In diameter, the Earth is quite large, so you could be anywhere.
To go to the 5 countries I have in mind would be a bad idea though.
Chad move evading the police.
Be ninja-like and keep hiding.

Comment: Spa is actually in Belgium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're all over the place!

*Can a dangerous criminal be caught?*

> **Can a da**ngerous criminal be caught?
>  Canada

*I ran away from the police.*

> **I ran** away from the police.
>  Iran

*Peruse this list of crimes.*

> **Peru**se this list of crimes.
>  Peru

*Chin and neck doctors were robbed.*

> **Chin a**nd neck doctors were robbed.
>  China

*Spa in the Netherlands is no longer one of my hiding spots.*

> **Spa in** the Netherlands is no longer one of my hiding spots.
>  Spain